# Creating AES-Key with C

Tags: c, encryption

How can I create an AES-Key using C? I like to create a pseudo-random 128-bit key using the rand function of C. I like to feed the rand function with a specific long number. I know that this is NOT secure and I know that I will get the same "random" number every time!

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    time_t epoch = 1427863786;
    printf("%d\n", rand((long)epoch));
}
```

Know I want to create the 128 bit key using the random number. How? Thanks!

Comment: Use srand(), not rand() for the seed.

Comment: I specifically have to use rand(), I know that it's not secure and I know that this outputs the same number everytime but that's exactly what I want!

Comment: No, it's not what you want. `rand()` is not a source of secure random data.

Comment: Why not? It's just for an example. I don't want to encrypt sensitive passwords, but just a sample text, to show how AES can be insecure.

Comment: @moe2801: AES is secure provided you use it correctly

Comment: @giorgi I know, but I want to prove how it can be insecure if used incorrectly, by having a predictable random number generator.

Comment: @moe2801: Well have a look at my answer, how using one call to rand you hope to get a 16 byte integer?

Answer (score 1):

You can even try something like this(assuming the fact that this is not secure is not bothering you):

```
unsigned char buf[16];
int i;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
    buf[i] = rand() % 256;
}
```

Since `rand` returns `int`(typical size 4 bytes), I doubt how in other way you can get 16 byte number using one call to `rand`.

Comment: Mind that many implementations of `rand()` are highly periodic in the lower-order bits. It's not uncommon for the LSB to alternate between 0 and 1, for instance!

Comment: @duskwuff: Yeah I see just OP specifically requested this

Comment: Is it even possible to generate a 128-bit key using the rand function?